# Visual Studio 2022 randomly pops "save as" window when triggering save command

Tags: visual-studio

As title, by pressing Ctrl+S or clicking the save icon in the toolbar, sometimes the "save as" window is displayed unexpectedly. This issue appears to occur randomly.

It's particularly frustrating for me because I have a network resource mapped at boot. When this resource is offline and I attempt to open or save a new file, the system becomes unresponsive for a while.

OS version is Windows 10 x64 and IDE version Visual Studio 2022 community 17.8.4